# case statement in order by clause is not working in HQL

Tags: java, hql

When i am using case statement in Hibernate Query with setMaxResults() and setFirstResult() it is showing wrong records. For example, my query is

`select code, text 
from dropDownTable 
where (code like '%meter%'  or text like '%meter%') 
order by  case 
  when text like 'meter%' or code like 'meter%' then 0 
  when text like '%meter' or code like '%meter' then 2 else 1 
end`

Now I am using `setMaxResults(fetchSize)` and `setFirstResult(fetchSize*fetchCount)` in Hibernate Query. It is showing same records when fetchCount is more than 1.

I am not getting point that when we are setting start index then why it is showing records which are before that index. Please help me out in this. Following is my java code:

```
Query managerQuery = session.createSQLQuery(dynamicQuery);
managerQuery.setMaxResults(fetchSize);
managerQuery.setFirstResult(fetchSize * fetchCount);
returnList = managerQuery.setResultTransformer(insensitiveAliasTransformer).list();
```

Comment: what is the value of `fetchSize`?